# Azure Change App Name Not Recognized by Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, member

Registered an app in Azure, granted Power BI API access to the app. Then renamed the app. Add the app in Power BI workspace member list by searching the new name (the old name is not searchable any more). But when browsing the members again, the old name shows in the member list.

Comment: Some clarification. I renamed the app a couple of years later after the app was initially created. Not right after.